# Отсортировать массив указателей с помощю сравнения строк

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, указатели

У меня есть классы: абстрактный класс Организм. Классы Животное и Растение наследуют класс Организм. Классы Мох и Травянистое растение наследуют класс Растение. Классы Зверь и Птица наследуют класс Животное.

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


//================ Parent class ==============//
class Organizm
{
protected:
    string name;
    int amount;
public:
    Organizm() : name(""), amount(0) {}
    Organizm(string name, int amount) : name(name), amount(amount) {}
    virtual ~Organizm() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual string getName() = 0;
    virtual int getAmount() = 0;
};
//============================================//

//======== Abstract derived classes ==========//
class Plant : public Organizm
{
protected:
    string location;
public:
    Plant() : Organizm(), location("") {}
    Plant(string name, int amount, string location) : Organizm(name, 
amount), location(location) {}
    virtual ~Plant() {}
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << " Name: " << this->name << endl;
        cout << " Amount: " << this->amount << endl;
        cout << " Location: " << this->location << endl;
    }
    virtual string getName() = 0;
    virtual int getAmount() = 0;
};

class Animal : public Organizm
{
protected:
    string movement;
public:
    Animal() : Organizm(), movement("") {}
    Animal(string name, int amount, string movement) : Organizm(name, 
amount), movement(movement) {}
    virtual ~Animal() {}
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << " Name: " << this->name << endl;
        cout << " Amount: " << this->amount << endl;
        cout << " Type of movement: " << this->movement << endl;
    }
    virtual string getName() = 0;
    virtual int getAmount() = 0;
};
//============================================//

//============= Derived classes ==============//
class Moss : public Plant
{
private:
    string colour;
public:
    Moss() : Plant(), colour("") {}
    Moss(string name, int amount, string location, string colour) : 
Plant(name, amount, location), colour(colour) {}
    ~Moss() {}
    void print()
    {
        Plant::print();
        cout << " Colour: " << this->colour << endl;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    int getAmount()
    {
        return this->amount;
    }
    istream& operator>>(Moss& newMoss)
    {
        cout << "Name of moss > ";
        cin >> this->name;
        cout << "Amount of moss > ";
        cin >> this->amount;
        cout << "Location of moss > ";
        cin >> this->location;
        cout << "Colour of moss > ";
        cin >> this->colour;
        return cin;
    }
};

class Herbaceous : public Plant
{
private:
    double height;
public:
    Herbaceous() : Plant(), height(0.0) {}
    Herbaceous(string name, int amount, string location, double height) : 
Plant(name, amount, location), height(height) {}
    ~Herbaceous() {}
    void print()
    {
        Plant::print();
        cout << " Height: " << this->height << " meters" << endl;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    int getAmount()
    {
        return this->amount;
    }
    istream& operator>>(Herbaceous& newHerbaceous)
    {
        cout << "Name of herbaceous > ";
        cin >> this->name;
        cout << "Amount of herbaceous > ";
        cin >> this->amount;
        cout << "Location of herbaceous > ";
        cin >> this->location;
        cout << "Height of herbaceous > ";
        cin >> this->height;
        return cin;
    }
};

class Beast : public Animal
{
private:
    string placeOfLiving;
public:
    Beast() : Animal(), placeOfLiving("") {}
    Beast(string name, int amount, string movement, string placeOfLiving) : 
Animal(name, amount, movement), placeOfLiving(placeOfLiving) {}
    ~Beast() {}
    void print()
    {
        Animal::print();
        cout << " Place of living: " << this->placeOfLiving << endl;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    int getAmount()
    {
        return this->amount;
    }
    istream& operator>>(Beast& newHerbaceous)
    {
        cout << "Name of beast > ";
        cin >> this->name;
        cout << "Amount of beast > ";
        cin >> this->amount;
        cout << "Type of movement of beast > ";
        cin >> this->movement;
        cout << "Place of living of beast > ";
        cin >> this->placeOfLiving;
        return cin;
    }
};

class Bird : public Animal
{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Bird() : Animal(), age(0) {}
    Bird(string name, int amount, string movement, int age) : Animal(name, 
amount, movement), age(age) {}
    ~Bird() {}
    void print()
    {
        Animal::print();
        cout << " Age: " << this->age << " year(s)" << endl;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
    int getAmount()
    {
         return this->amount;
    }
    istream& operator>>(Bird& newHerbaceous)
    {
        cout << "Name of bird > ";
        cin >> this->name;
        cout << "Amount of bird > ";
        cin >> this->amount;
        cout << "Type of movement of bird > ";
        cin >> this->movement;
        cout << "Age of bird > ";
        cin >> this->age;
        return cin;
    }
};
//============================================//
```

Мне нужно отсортировать растения по названию в алфавитном порядке.
Я сделал сортировку пузырьком, но почему то она не сортирует.

Можете указать где ошибка ?

```
void sortPlantsByNames(Plant **arr, int size)
{
    Plant* temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j]->getName() > arr[j + 1]->getName())
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    const size_t amountOfPlants = 6;
    Plant* newArrOfPlants[amountOfPlants];

    newArrOfPlants[0] = new Moss("Sphagnum", 5, "swamps", "white");
    newArrOfPlants[1] = new Herbaceous("Tree", 4, "forests", 7.4);
    newArrOfPlants[2] = new Moss("Polytrichum", 15, "forests", "brown");
    newArrOfPlants[3] = new Herbaceous("Bush", 3, "shrubs", 1.5);
    newArrOfPlants[4] = new Herbaceous("Grass", 100500, "fields", 0.1);
    newArrOfPlants[5] = new Moss("Marchantia polymorpha", 7, "forest","green");

    const size_t amountOfAnimals = 4;
    Animal* newArrOfAnimals[amountOfAnimals];

    newArrOfAnimals[0] = new Beast("Wolf", 17, "ground", "forests");
    newArrOfAnimals[1] = new Bird("Stork", 12, "air", 2);
    newArrOfAnimals[2] = new Bird("Swan" , 8, "air and water", 3);
    newArrOfAnimals[3] = new Beast("Talpa", 26, "ground", "holes");

    const size_t SIZE = 10;
    Organizm* newArrOfOrganizms[SIZE];

    newArrOfOrganizms[0] = newArrOfAnimals[0];
    newArrOfOrganizms[1] = newArrOfAnimals[1];
    newArrOfOrganizms[2] = newArrOfAnimals[2];
    newArrOfOrganizms[3] = newArrOfAnimals[3];
    newArrOfOrganizms[4] = newArrOfPlants[0];
    newArrOfOrganizms[5] = newArrOfPlants[1];
    newArrOfOrganizms[6] = newArrOfPlants[2];
    newArrOfOrganizms[7] = newArrOfPlants[3];
    newArrOfOrganizms[8] = newArrOfPlants[4];
    newArrOfOrganizms[9] = newArrOfPlants[5];

    sortPlantsByNames(newArrOfPlants, amountOfPlants);

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPlants; i++)
    {
        cout << "Plant #" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
        newArrOfPlants[i]->print();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Не проще ли использовать контейнеры стандартной библиотеки, вместо динамических массивов? (`std::vector` или `std::list`, например)
Скомпилировал ваш код(не читал) и у меня в выводе все по алфавиту, в чем конкретно проблема? http://imgur.com/a/r7qjQ

Comment: *"Я сделал сортировку пузырьком"* -- один вопрос: зачем? Чем вам C++ не угодил?

Comment: *"Классы Зверь и Птица наследуют класс Животное"* -- sorry за оффтопик, но тут огромное спасибо могу сказать, что не путаете зверей и животных :)

Answer (score 1):

Явных проблем с работой вашего кода я не увидел, и видимо, работает он так как и должен, но есть несколько моментов, на которые хотелось бы обратить ваше внимание.

- Не советую вам открывать все пространство имен `using namespace std;` так как это может привести к конфликту имен. Например, вы напишите свою функцию `sort()` и захотите использовать алгоритм стандартной библиотеки `sort()`, речь о котором пойдет позже, то по умолчанию у вас вызовется та функция, которую вы написали сами. Это может привести к очень трудноотлавливаемым багам во времени исполнения. Согласитесь, не так сложно написать `std::`
- При описании класса поля, которые описывают множество возможных значений(например поле `Animal::movement`, которое хранит тип движения), вы храните в `std::string`. Это может вам добавить очень много проблем, т.к. при расширении программы вы уже не будете помнить как именно пишется тип движения, а `ground` и `Ground` это уже разные строки и при сравнении они не будут эквивалентны. В вашем случае будет намного удобнее все подобные поля хранить в `enum` или `enum class`. Например `enum class MovementType {GROUND, AIR, WATER};` и работать с этим типом. Так ваш код будет намного проще читать и расширять.
- При обращении к свойствам класса из методов не обязательно повсюды использовать `this`
- В классе все поля по умолчанию приватные. Не обязательно после объявления класса явно указывать `private:` это и так очевидно.
- Вместо функций `print()` вы вполне можете перегрузить оператор вывода в поток `<<`
- То, что я уже писал в коментарии. Намного проще использовать контейнеры стандартной библиотеки. Так ваш код будет намного проще переносимым и работать с ним будет приятнее.
  Например такой код

  ```
  const size_t amountOfPlants = 6;
  Plant* newArrOfPlants[amountOfPlants];

  newArrOfPlants[0] = new Moss("Sphagnum", 5, "swamps", "white");
  newArrOfPlants[1] = new Herbaceous("Tree", 4, "forests", 7.4);
  newArrOfPlants[2] = new Moss("Polytrichum", 15, "forests", "brown");
  newArrOfPlants[3] = new Herbaceous("Bush", 3, "shrubs", 1.5);
  newArrOfPlants[4] = new Herbaceous("Grass", 100500, "fields", 0.1);
  newArrOfPlants[5] = new Moss("Marchantia polymorpha", 7, "forest","green");
  ```

  можно заменить на

  ```
  std::vector<Plant*> plants;  
  plants.push_back(new Moss("Sphagnum", 5, "swamps", "white"));  
  ...
  plants.push_back(new Herbaceous("Grass", 100500, "fields", 0.1));
  ```

  Согласитесь, в таком виде рабоать с данными намного приятнее.
- Из предыдущего пункта вытекает следующее. В стандартной библиотеке `C++` существуют алгоритмы для работы с контейнерам, определенные в заголовочном файле `algorithm` (`#include <algorithm>`).
  В вашем случае, вместо того чтобы писать велосипед, можно воспользоваться уже готовыми решениями, которые работают намного эффективнее и не убивают переносимость вашего кода. Я говорю сейчас про сортировку. Существует [алгоритм](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) `std::sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp )`, который принимает итераторы на начало и конец сортируемой последовательности(`first`, `last`, и функциональный объект, который отвечает за сравнение (`comp`).
  Такми образом, вам необходимо всего лишь описать правило сравнение ваших объектов.
  Например, для сравнения по имени вы можете сделать так:

  ```
  struct Compare
  {  
      bool operator () (Organizm* fst, Organizm* snd)  
      { return fst->getName() > snd->getName(); }  
  };
  ```

  И теперь просто вызвать функцию `std::sort(plants.begin(), plants.end(), Compare());`, которая сделает все то, что делали вы.
  Либо можно заменить структуру `Compare` на лямбда-функцию

  ```
  std::sort(newArrOfPlants.begin(), newArrOfPlants.end(),  
  [](Organizm* fst, Organizm* snd) { return fst->getName() < snd->getName(); });
  ```

  В итоге, вы заменяете целый блок сложночитаемого кода на 1-2 строки.